# Getting a single element with JQuery and SenchaTouch

Tags: jquery, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm writing an article on SenchaTouch and want to compare the basic Ext.Get to the Equivalent in JQuery.  I'm a little confused and want to make sure I get this right.

In SenchaTouch, to setthe innerHtml I use Ext.get and pass it the element I want.  In JQuery, I pass a css selector? (I assume that is what the # does).  Am I right on this?  In JQuery, is there a way to do the same "GetElementById" type thing?

Also, I'm a little confused on why JQuery is not returning an array?  Is that because there can only be one item marked with the same ID in the DOM?

I know, kind of novice questions, but I really want to make sure I undestand this correctly.

```
   Ext.application({
        name: 'MyApp',
        launch: function () {
            Ext.get('div1').setHtml('Ext Set this');
        }

    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div2').html('JQuery Set this');
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById()` returns a DOM element, it's native JavaScript and will be much more faster than `Ext.get()` or `$(#id)`

`$('#id')` which is a type of jQuery selector won't return an array, it returns a jQuery [object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) which allow you to call whatever jQuery methods that is supposed to affect the elements found. It never returns null even if the jQuery object contains no elements, it will treated as empty object and simply do nothing.

So basically, Ext.get() is not exactly the same as `document.getElementById()` in javascript or `$('#id')` in jQuery since it allow more than just the `id` but an existing HTMLElement, or a `Ext.Element`.